# WHAT Can add To Scan Folder Have No Name

Tags: virus

i Scan flash Disk using this .Bat file to Delete Viruss ets..

So WHAT Can I add To Scan Folder Have No Name ..see pic

```
@ECHO OFF
MODE CON:Cols=65 Lines=20

ECHO            -!- UN HIDE -!-
ECHO.
ECHO "Enter Drive letter" 
SET /P driveletter=
ECHO.
Attrib -S -H -A /S /D  %driveletter%:\*.*

DEL /S  %driveletter%:\*.lnk
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\*.vbe
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\*.vbs
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\*.tmp
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\x.mpeg
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\Thumbs.db
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\_WEQZ.init
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\desktop.ini
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\Autorun.inf
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\Skypee.exe
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\AutoIt3.exe
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\Kristans.exe
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\Microsoft.dat

PAUSE
ECHO   DONE :)
EXIT
```

[image]

.Thanks .In .Advance

Answer (score 1):

The folder does have a name - the name is just blanks or anything else that
is not visible.

I suggest to list all folders to a text file by opening the Command prompt
(CMD), navigate to `F:` and enter the command:

```
cd /d F:\
dir /b /a:d > list.txt
```

Use a text editor to open the file and select the text-string that stands
for the name, even if it's all blanks.

Then use the following command, pasting the copied contents:

```
DEL /S  %driveletter%:\"copied text"
```

Comment: what is the  list.txt and what "copied text" ؟ DID Example

Comment: `list.txt` is a text file. You will find in it a blank line which is the name of the folder. Select blindly the name from the beginning of the line to the end (usually key Home and then Shift-End), do Ctrl-C and paste it into the DEL command.